# Excel online sheet, how to import to SSIS

Tags: python, excel, ssis, etl

i want to know if a can get a sheet from excel online and import to sql. There is a way to do that? I saw some tools for that but i have to pay it for.

I tried to use python, but i havent any success

Comment: AFAIK if you have a business license of Microsoft 365 you should be able to use Power Automate to connect Excel to SQL

Comment: My guess that since you can use Python then you should be able to use an OleDB connection and use SQL against the spreadsheet. https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/xlsx-files/